# Maven does not see my updated java file to compile

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to run a java file build in maven by using

```
/zhome/9e/b/129343/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.matsim.contrib.ev.example.MyRunEvExample"
```

However, although the location of an input file is: `final String ChargersCoords = "test/input/org/matsim/contrib/ev/example/RunEvExample/new_10_test_ChargersFred_Feed_Tab.csv";`

I get the following error: `An exception occured while executing the Java class. zhome/9e/b/129343/Downloads/new_10_test_ChargersFred_Feed_Tab.csv (No such file or directory)`

It seems like it does not see the new location of the file although I have saved the file before running it.
Does it need to compile first before running or that's not the issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to compile first: you are executing a plugin goal without any attached [maven build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Possible solutions:

1. either use `mvn compile exec:java`
2. [create an execution](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) in the `exec-maven-plugin` and attach it to a phase, e.g. `test` (not recommended).
3. Create an execution and do not attach it to a phase. Instead, run it by using the `@` separator. [More details in this how-to](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2021/04/05/maven-plugin-configuration/).
4. create a profile which will attach the execution to a test.